# Why am I getting class path resource [src/main/resources/databaseconfig.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist error?

Tags: java, spring

[image: Workspace arrangement]

When I try to run App.java I get the following error .

```
 Error creating bean with name 'dbase': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [src/main/resources/databaseconfig.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Here is my spring configuration file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

    <import resource="SpringCollections.xml"/> <!-- Loading multiple Configuration files     -->
     <import resource="SpringBeans.xml"/>
     <util:properties id="dbase" location="src/main/resources/databaseconfig.properties"/>


</beans>
```

Any idea what Im doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried this: location="classpath:/src...

Comment: Doesnt work. Same error.

Comment: I would expect you to be using `location="/databaseconfig.properties"`.

Comment: @Rob: That solves the runtime error. However, the value populated is still `null` and not the value in the properties file.

Comment: @KodeSeeker I have added this as an answer, so the next person that has your symptoms can find it. It sounds like you are on to your next problem (what is wrong with your spring configuration). You should ask about this as a separate question (if you cannot solve it on your own).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the files in your `src/main/resources` directory get put on your classpath. Therefore, you should be looking for your properties file at `/databaseconfig.properties`.

Comment: That was totally it.